# String.contain in object serialization for persian String

Tags: java, android

i have problem with String.contain in object serialization for persian String.
structuresMain.get(i).getFirstName() =="کاربر"
my code is:

```
   edtSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            String s = charSequence.toString().trim();//----> s == "کار"

          if( structuresMain.get(i).getFirstName().contains(query)){

                //do something
            }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

but Return false and dosent found string!
Please helpe me.i am searching long time but dosent found my answer

Answer (score 1):

It is because of your characters. The first character you have used in "کاربر" which is "ک" is not the same with you have used in second one "کار" which is "ک". In order to fix this problem, you have to **unify** these characters:

In order to do that, you have to use below code on both strings:

```
private String unifiedString(String input) {
    return input.replace("ک", "ک");
}
```

Same problem exists for "ی" character which you have to handle it like this.

Comment: i have problem with lot of character. what can i do?which is the the best solotion?

Comment: As far as I know, these problem exists on some limited characters. There isn't any other solution because they are really different characters with different ASCii codes. So, you have to unify them and there is no any other solution.

Comment: ok thank you.thats work.but if i solve all character problem,i writing new answer for another person

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem with A. Badakhshan Answer.
this problem is for arabic and persian character.
in arabic two character structure is difrent with persian character.if searching as persian,should replace them to persian structure.this is complet code:

```
 public String unifiedString(String input) {
   return input.replaceAll("ک", "ك").replaceAll("ی","ي");
}
```